# mmap and string operations in assembler

Tags: string, assembly, x86, mmap, gnu-assembler

I am trying to code something that allocates some memory for a string and fills that memory with random characters.
Now I decided to go the way of mmap-syscalls, without using malloc functions.

Here is my code:

```
.code32
.data
    random: .ascii "/dev/random\0"

.section .data
    c: .ascii "t"   #just a test static character, for test
    n: .ascii "\n"  #end of string
.text
    .global _start
    _start:


pushl $0    # offset of 0
pushl $-1 # the file handle of the open file
pushl $33     # MAP_SHARED flag set to write changed data back to file
pushl $3     # PROT_READ and PROT_WRITE permissions
pushl $42   
pushl $0     # Allow the system to select the location in memory to start
movl %esp,%ebx   # copy the parameters location to EBX
movl $90,%eax    # set the system call value
int $0x80
movl %eax,%edi  #the adress of allocated memory is stored in edi
pushl %eax  #save the adress on stack 
movl $42, %ecx  #now i want to generate 42 random symbols and print them
loop:
    dec %ecx        
    pushl %ecx                              #generate a random number, using the kernel Entropy Collector
    movl $5,%eax                            # sys_open
    movl $random,%ebx                       # Filename string

    movl $0,%ecx      # O_RDONLY flag
    int $0x80
                                    # Read one random number
    movl %eax,%ebx     # The result of sys_open
    movl $3,%eax       # sys_read
    movl (%esp),%ecx     # The stack is our buffer
    movl $1,%edx       # 
    int $0x80       #random number on stack
    popl %eax       #eax represents the random number
    movl $100,%ebx
    divl %ebx       #modulo 223
    leal 34(%edx),%eax
    stosb           #load a random char into allocated memory           
    popl %ecx
    cmpl $0,%ecx
    jne loop

movl $4,%eax        #syscall write
movl $1,%ebx
movl $43,%edx
popl %ecx       #pop the saved adress of string
int  $0x80

movl $1,%eax        #exit
int $0x80
```

`

which causes a segfault in `MOVSB` - operation.

So I am not sure about a couple of things:

1. The way I just push integers between 33 and 255 to `ESI` before the `MOVSB`, hoping that the integer will be recognized as an ascii sign, for which it stands.
2. The way I allocate memory
3. Also not quite sure about the correctness of the `LEAL` - operation,
   which aims to just move through the allocated (42??) bytes of memory each time jumping to a new byte. Although this one can not cause the segfault as it comes after the error-causing `MOVSB`.

---

##### EDIT: Stack faults fixed by setting correct flags in mmap-call and changing movsb to stosb

Comment: You can use `strace` to examine system calls. Also, you should check the returned pointer.

Comment: Are you trying to mmap stdin for read-write? Also keep the stack balanced (plus I'm not sure if 32-bit processes can use the red-zone on 64-bit machines)

Comment: Nope, no red zone in 32-bit code. The underlying architecture of the machine doesn't matter. As far as your code is concerned, it's running on a 32-bit processor, and those calling conventions apply. You'll find information about the various calling conventions in the [tag:x86] tag wiki.

Comment: the syscall for mmap is copy pasted from another stackoverflow post concerning mmap. Running it separately works (no segfault).
is my string handling correct?

Comment: After the mmap syscall the eax (in which the pointer to allocated area should be returned) has the value -19

Comment: setting of PROT_READ | PROT_Write flags should let me write in the mmaped memory?

Comment: You can use strace to examine system calls. Also, you should check the returned pointer. – Jester 28 mins ago  ----

Could you give me a hint how to check the value?

Comment: You just did. It's `-19` meaning error. You look up the code and that gives `-ENODEV`. If you want to use `mmap` to allocate memory you should pass the flag `MAP_ANONYMOUS`. You didn't do that, so the `mmap` was trying to operate on `stdin` and that does not support `mmap` (and wouldn't do what you want anyway). Note that the [manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) says to set `fd` to `-1` to ensure compatibility.

Comment: Thank you very much! I understood that I should use `MAP_ANONYMOUS`, so set `fd` to -1, But after this change the `mmap-call` returns -12 with a segfault.
Where exactly can I look which error the returned integer corresponds to?

Comment: In your `errno.h`, but I believe `strace` also prints it for you. Just to check, did you actually **use** `MAP_ANONYMOUS`?

Comment: What operating system is this for?

Comment: hi, sry the quite long delay of my reaction. My system is Ubuntu. 
Anyways I fixed my problem with ONE segfault. It was caused by the wrong setting of flags.
The other segfault is caused by my generating-of-random-characters - technique. When I declare a test character  in data segment and push it in 42 allocated bytes, it works. When I try to let the "random integer" mod 100 + 33  be interpreted as the number of an ascii character it segfaults.
There must be something completely wrong about the way I operate with Ascii

Comment: `movsb` is a memory-to-memory copy, what you need is simply `movb %dl, (%edi)` I suppose. Also, you should zero `%edx` before division.

Comment: ye, already fixed that :).